# Is it possible to move the method references in Visual Studio 2022 to be under the method declaration?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I really like the method references in Visual Studio 2022, but when I add a summary to a method, it confuses me visually when the summary is above the method references. Is it possible for the references to be moved below the method declaration?
For example instead of:

```
///summary///
2 references
public void SomeMethod() 
    {
          
    }
```

To be:

```
///summary///
public void SomeMethod()
2 references
    {
 
    }
```

[image]

I couldn't find anything in the options menu.

Comment: I don't think this can be done, but I would find it confusing, personally, as it would be splitting two related pieces of code. Maybe you can raise it as as a feature suggestion.

Comment: For the time being, Microsoft has not added this setting option. So it is temporarily impossible to change the display position of CodeLens. For the time being, CodeLens will indeed cause inconvenience during the development process. Another way is to disable CodeLens directly, but this method is too extreme. So I suggest you post an improvement idea for Visual Studio [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home). and get more people to vote. The more people have opinions, the easier it is to be heard.

Comment: You could use _Help | Provide Feedback | Request a Feature_ to request this.

Answer (score 0):

The references are part of CodeLens. There is no option for the Visual Studio editor to show the CodeLens below the method signature. However, the CodeLens windows can be docked (see "[Q: Can I move the CodeLens heads-up display?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/find-code-changes-and-other-history-with-codelens?view=vs-2022#q-can-i-move-the-codelens-heads-up-display)" for details).